# Does a working nomodeset means the gpu isn't defective?

Tags: boot, drivers, amd-graphics, 20.10, gpu

I have an M6600 which runs Kubuntu 20.04. I have problems with the screen sometimes. The laptop boots and I am able to log in. After some while I get a brownish display with vertical stripes. Sometimes it doesn't show the login screen.

What always works is setting `nomodeset` in grub. Does this mean my problem is software related? I want to check first before I buy a gpu (even the M6600 gpus are quite expensive right now).

Here is some more information about the M6600:

```
System:
  Host: Precision-M6600 Kernel: 5.8.0-48-generic x86_64 
  bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5 
  Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Precision M6600 v: 01 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 04YY4M v: A00 
  serial: <superuser/root required> BIOS: Dell v: A04 
  date: 07/11/2011 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 86.9 Wh condition: 86.9/98.2 Wh (88%) 
CPU:
  Info: Dual Core Intel Core i5-2520M [MT MCP] speed: 2394 MHz 
  min/max: 800/3200 MHz 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Blackcomb [Radeon HD 6970M/6990M] driver: N/A 
  Device-2: Ricoh type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  Display: x11 server: X.org 1.20.9 driver: vesa FAILED: ati 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon 
  Message: No advanced graphics data found on this system. 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network driver: e1000e 
  Device-2: Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 driver: iwlwifi 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 592.27 GiB used: 29.86 GiB (5.0%) 
Info:
  Processes: 204 Uptime: 22m Memory: 7.73 GiB 
  used: 1.48 GiB (19.1%) Shell: Bash inxi: 3.1.07
```

**UPDATE:** So I found out about the ePSA diagnostics and I get an "video memory integrity test discrepancy" error. It seems safe to say that there is an hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

By using the the nomodeset parameter during start up are instructing the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

Basically you are saying do not use my video driver use this generic one from the computer BIOS.

This does not mean that for sure the video card is bad but that you are most likely using the wrong drivers.

Make sure you are running the correct driver for the video card/chip set you are using.